# jqGrid sortable with offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-sortable

I have been using the following script for drag and drop oredering in jQGrid and saving the order to database. Once the order of the row is changed, it will order the complete grid from 1 and reload the grid with updated order. Now I need a modified functionality.

```
jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('sortableRows', {
    items: '.jqgrow:not(.unsortable)',
    update : function(e,ui) {
    var lista = jQuery(grid_selector).getDataIDs();
    var idArray = new Array();

    for (i=0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        var rowData=jQuery(grid_selector).getRowData(lista[i]);
        var valArray = {
            uuid: rowData.uuid,
            prize_order: i + 1
        }
        idArray.push(valArray);
    }
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(idArray);

    $.ajax({
        url: "myurl/update_function",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {display_order_array : jsonString}, 
    })
    .done(function() {

        $(grid_selector).trigger('reloadGrid');
        var tId;
        $("#messageDiv").html('<p class="alert alert-success">Order modified successfully</p>');
        $("#messageDiv").hide().slideDown();
        clearTimeout(tId);
        tId = setTimeout(function(){
          $("#messageDiv").hide();        
        }, 3000);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        grid_selector.trigger('reloadGrid');
        var tId;
        $("#messageDiv").html('<p class="alert alert-danger">There is some issues in modifying order !!</p>');
        clearTimeout(tId);
        tId = setTimeout(function(){
          $("#messageDiv").hide();        
        }, 3000);

    })

    }
});
```

When I order a list which has order starting from say 80, it needs to be ordered from 80 and not from 1. Also if I intechange two rows say 85 and 90, only the rows from 85 needs to be re ordered and it shouldn't affect the orders of rows between 80 and 85.